# Jboss server shutdown on localhost

Tags: jboss7.x

I'm trying to set up localhost for a new project I'm working on and the localhost Jboss server is shutting own with the following message [The console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNUaB.jpg) . I'm on windows 11 and running Jboss AS

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of WildFly or JBoss EAP are you using?

Comment: Jboss EAP 7.3.5